# What are Fuzzy integrals?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

How could you define "Fuzzy Integral"? Could you recomended me any interesting book to self study about Fuzzy integrals?

Thanks

Comment: Websites will be apreciated too.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the book

[Zhenyuan Wang and George J. Klir , Fuzzy measure theory,  Springer, 1992](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780306442605)

The authors provide a rigorous mathematical development of fuzzy (Sugeno) integrals in Chapter 7.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough definition, a  **fuzzy integral**  is a generalization of traditional integration techniques (e.g. the Lebesgue integral), but where the measure used is  *non-additive*  or  *fuzzy* .  For practical use, it's a way of summing up or averaging a set of inputs in a way that takes into account interaction or other relationships between input sources.

Some introductory videos here:
[Fuzzy integrals YouTube playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoGwkQIHTOVNZNSYDAQHtEIWkqszhpT5d)

Then the following books:

[An introduction to aggregation functions in R](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319467610) -
A fairly simple introductory book on aggregation functions. Has fuzzy integrals as the last chapter - this is if you're interested in these functions from a data summary/machine learning perspective.

[Discrete Fuzzy Measures](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030153045) -
Or a more in-depth introduction, including a chapter on some different fuzzy integrals and their history.